# VSCode Python Test Discovery fails？

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VS Code version: version Version: 1.69.2 (Universal))

Extension version (available under the Extensions sidebar): v2021.12.1559732655

OS and version: MacOS 12.3.1

Python version: 3.6.8

Type of virtual environment used (N/A | venv | virtualenv | conda | ...): venv

Relevant/affected Python packages and their versions: pytest==7.0.1

problem:

```
~/wkspace/one_service/.venv/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir ~/wkspace/one_service -s --cache-clear tests
cwd: ~/wkspace/one_service
[ERROR 2022-7-10 14:19:35.323]: Error discovering pytest tests:
 r [Error]: LOADING_FILE: app.__init__.py
BASE_DIR in app.__init__.py: /Users/77/wkspace/one_service
SRE::START_ENV::[None]
b'\xe5\x8a\xa0\xe8\xbd\xbd\xe9\x85\x8d\xe7\xbd\xae\xe6\x96\x87\xe4\xbb\xb6\xe4\xb8\xba\xef\xbc\x9aenv_local.py'
ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/77/wkspace/one_service/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:3: in <module>
    from app import app
app/__init__.py:165: in <module>
    print(f"os.environ\u73af\u5883\u53d8\u91cf\uff1a{os.environ}")
E   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-14: ordinal not in range(128)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/77/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "/Users/77/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "/Users/77/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/pytest/_discovery.py", line 44, in discover
    raise Exception("pytest discovery failed (exit code {})".format(ec))
Exception: pytest discovery failed (exit code 4)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/tiantian/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/out/client/extension.js:32:39076)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
```

Comment: Please show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I added the full error traceback now, tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the above answers solved my problem, I recently google the information myself and found the root cause.
I added the following statement to the conftest.py file

```
print(sys.stdout.encoding, '----',
      os.getenv('PYTHONIOENCODING'))
```

The result obtained is

> US-ASCII --- utf-8

Checked the documentation to confirm the environment variables that affect sys.stdout.encoding

> LC_CTYPE LANG

because the test find script was found to execute successfully in terminal.

```
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- - rootdir
```

In the terminal, look at these two environment variables and add them to the .env file.

> LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
> LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"

The problem is solved.

Comment: Specific reasons and details can be found in https://peps.python.org/pep-0538/#motivation

Answer (score 1):

First, please check whether the file encoding format in the lower right corner of vscode is `utf-8` (if not, please modify it).

[image]

Then, **based on your error message, provide the following solutions:**

Method 1: Add **utf-8** encoding format at the beginning of the file

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

Method 2: Use the following command in the terminal to update the encoding format

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

Method 3: Find the wrong place in your code and clearly indicate how it is coded

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
 
s = 'error' 
s.encode('utf-8')
```

**If the above solutions do not resolve your issue, please show a more detailed error message and your error code.**

Comment: I have tried all the methods above, but none of them worked.

Comment: Try using `python3.7` and above. and update to the latest version of vscode. My machine: `python3.9.13`, `vscode 1.70.0`. Run your code without errors. 或者在字符串中直接使用中文。